# Xamarin Forms - Media Controls

Tags: xamarin.forms, media-player

I can find lots of articles on how to play my own media.  But I'm trying to add media controls to skip whatever is playing music in the background, be it Apple Music, Amazon, Spotify e.t.c?

I've seen other apps that can do this.  I'm looking for a cross platform solution or ideally the relevant SDKs on each platform, so I can build my own abstraction.

TIA

Comment: What apps allow you to control the playback of other apps?

Comment: Intervals on iOS, it's a HIIT interval timer.